# update local branches after git fetch

Tags: git

After a command like `$ git fetch origin -a`

I can read a log like this:

```
remote: Counting objects: 43, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (43/43), done.
remote: Total 43 (delta 21), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (43/43), done.
From https://bitbucket.org/...
   e51234feb..212348ca85  feature/PROJCT-1234 -> origin/feature/PROJCT-1234
   d6d123403..ee501234a  master                -> origin/master
```

And after this fetch whenever I run

```
git rebase master
```

console returns

```
Current branch feature/PROJCT-1234 is up to date.
```

But if I run

```
git rebase origin/master
```

The rebase complete its job.

So the question is. To avoid to type `origin/...` each time. Is there a way to `git fetch origin` and have all branches with updates, ... pulled down?

Comment: And get merge conflicts for many branches? :) If you want to always work with the remote versions of code - why use local branches at all? Checkout remote-tracking branches and work in detached mode. Personally I haven't used local branches for a long time now..

Comment: Not directly related to your question, but there's no point in using `-a` with `git fetch` here. The `-a` option means *append to `FETCH_HEAD`*. If you aren't using `FETCH_HEAD` manually—and there's no reason for you to be doing that—there's no reason to keep the previous `FETCH_HEAD` contents around either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on `master` which you want to update, just do:

```sh
git pull
#or
git pull -r
```

if you want update `master` when working on other branch do:

```sh
git fetch origin master:master
```

There is no straight way to update all local branches. Rationale is simple: you should be able to check what has been fetched from remote repository.
Any local branch updates should be performed only on your aware request, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You just do a merge *origin/master* is just another branch like *master*.

git fetch will update *origin/master* and afterwards you do git merge (or rebase) onto *master*

So in short

```
// sitting on master
git fetch

//useful to inspect changes before actually applying
git diff origin/master 

git merge origin/master
```

Alternatively a shortcut for the above fetch / merge is the pull.
Beware though there is a trap since fetch merges origin/master onto master and if it is not a fastforwad merge, you will get an awkward merge from master to master in your history.

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge#_fast_forward_merge

You can find a good lecture on what actually a branch is here -> https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

Once you realize it is just a pointer, things get a lot more clearer imo.

Cheers !

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Very useful. The focus of my question would be the fact that sometimes master is not aligned to origin/master. And you gave me few points to deep think about this kind of issue. Thank you very much.